# Can't add line to scatterplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I made a scatterplot in R of some rows of data over 4 years. It's this data (I can't post images)

```
Energy <- c(7.96, 8.16, 8.35, 8.82)
CO2 <- c(7.19, 2.84, 2.13, 1.64)
Water <- c(17.18,NA,19.23,28.86)
Trash <- c(65.04,NA,30.22,33.46)
Year <- factor(c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"))
Apple <-data.frame(Energy, CO2, Water, Trash, Year)
Apple.long <- melt(Apple, id = "Year", measure = c("Energy", "CO2", "Water",     "Trash"))
```

This works pretty good. Using ggplot gives a good scatterplot

```
ggplot(Apple.long, aes(Year, value, colour=variable, group=1)) + geom_point()
```

I want to connect these points with a line. When I change the geom_point() to a geom_line() a bunch of weird lines appear, some of them vertical and some only connecting 2 points. I assume the NA's in Water and Trash throw off those lines but I don't understand why the others don't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if this is what you are after. `ggplot(Apple.long, aes(Year, value, colour=variable, group= variable)) + geom_line() `.

Comment: Perfect. And it makes so much sense, too! Thanks!